# maximum sum subarray of window k algorithm not returning correctly for start index

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sub-array

Here is my code for maxSum subarray

given input array -> [110,-4,3,6,7,11] and k =3,  the code should give [110,-4,3] since that is the subarray which has maximum sum.

I have implemented the algorithm. it works for all the input except one. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong.

```
public class MaxSumSizeK {


        private static int getMaxAvgSubarrayStartIndex(int input[], int k)
        {
            int n = input.length;
            if (k > n)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("k should be less than or equal to n" );      
            if(k == n) {
                return 0;    
            }

            int sum = input[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
                sum += input[i];

            int maxSum = sum;
            int maxSumIndex = 0;

            for (int i = k; i < n; i++){
                sum = sum - input[i-k] + input[i] ;
                if (sum > maxSum){
                    maxSum = sum;
                    maxSumIndex = i-k;
                }
            }
            return maxSumIndex+1;
        }

        public static void printMaxAvgSubarray(int[] input, int k) {
            System.out.print("Maximum average subarray of length "  + k + " is:  " );
            int index = getMaxAvgSubarrayStartIndex(input, k);
            for(int i =0 ; i < k; i++) {
                System.out.print(input[index++] + " " );
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] input = {11, -8, 16, -7, 24, -2, 300};
            int k = 3;
            printMaxAvgSubarray(input, k);
            System.out.println();
            int[] input1 = {110, -8, 16, -7, 24, -2, 3};
            printMaxAvgSubarray(input1, k);
            System.out.println();
            int[] input2 = {11, -8, 16, -7, 24, -2, 3};
            printMaxAvgSubarray(input2, k);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Maximum average subarray of length 3 is:  24 -2 300 
Maximum average subarray of length 3 is:  -8 16 -7 
Maximum average subarray of length 3 is:  16 -7 24
```

for input1, I do not see the expected answer which should be "110, -8, 16". I tried changing the return statement to "maxSumIndex" instead of "maxSumIndex+1". that breaks the other two inputs.

kindly provide your thoughs

Comment: Why is [110,-4,3] the maximum sum of [110,-4,3,6,7,11]? Your expectation looks like you want to print the first items out.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Maybe its only subset of consecutive numbers? So you can't hop around?   But yes i would like to know how that is the largest sum

Comment: Largest sum of 3 elements in array `110,-4,3,6,7,11` is `110+11+7` and it is `128`, so that's why I ask..

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis: it is subarray meaning it is consecutive. 110,11,7 is not consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two errors:

1. `maxSumIndex = i-k;` should be `maxSumIndex = i-k+1;` i-k - it is first index of previous array, not current maximal one
2. `return maxSumIndex+1;` should be `return maxSumIndex;` otherway in case of index 0 (ie first 3 items are maximal) - you will return 1, which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        int n = input.length;
        if (k > n)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("k should be less than or equal to n" );
        if (k < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("k should be greater than 0" );      
        if(k == n) {
            return 0;    
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            sum += input[i];

        int maxSum = sum;
        int maxSumIndex = 0;

        for (int j = 1; j < n-k; j++){
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
                sum = sum + (int) Math.abs(input[i+j]);
            }
            if (sum > maxSum){
                maxSum = sum;
                maxSumIndex = i-k;
            }
        } 
        return maxSumIndex;
```

Comment: you could do with one for loop instead of nested one